# jira soap api: attach screenshot applet

Tags: php, soap, jira

i am working with php and jira soap api and i wanted to know, that the jira soap service provide a single function for attaching files to the issues, is there any way to embed the attach screen shot applet through soap or any other way, has anybody else implemented this before? please i need help with that.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution, embedded the code provided by the jira and it worked. Thanks anyways